# Force objects to implement Comparable with protocol gives protocol can only be used as a generic constraint

Tags: swift

I'm having an array of objects. Now I want to force that those objects are implementing Comparable.

So I created a protocol like this:

```
protocol Foo: Comparable { }
```

Everything goes fine except when I create the array:

```
let array: [Foo] = [obj1, ..]
```

Then suddenly the compiler complains:

`Protocol 'Foo' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type` requirements

Is there another way to do this?

**EDIT**

```
class View: UIView {
    let viewModel: SomeViewModel
}

class SomeViewModel {
     let views: [UIView]
}
```

Comment: What type is obj1?

Comment: Obj1 is a class that extends UIView. The UIView has a viewModel and from that viewModel I want to use a property to sort the array on. Maybe I'm seeing it to complex.

Comment: Add the code here.

Comment: The error basically means that a statement like "an array of `Foo` objects", just like "an array of `Comparable` objects" is meaningless, since one type that conforms to `Comparable` (say, `Date`) could be completely different from another type that conforms to `Comparable` (say, `String`). That happens when you have a protocol with an associated type or a protocol that refers to `Self`. Instead, create an array of `[View]`, and extend `View` to conform to `Comparable`

Comment: Added the code I just want the views array from SomeViewModel to be Comparable.

Comment: @newDev how can I do that my views are really UIViews because those are all different to put in my stackview

Comment: I think you're asking an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question. Restate the question based on what you're actually trying to achieve by comparing views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when people add this conformance, they're trying to do something like sort a `[Foo]` or find the minimum value, but that won't work, even if you could make this Array, because Comparable requires that a type be comparable *to its own type*, not to others matching the protocol. So for, example, given your `array`, you couldn't use `array.min()` to find the minimum element, because Comparable does not require that a Foo be comparable to a Foo, only that things that conform to Foo can be compared to themselves.

Instead, you need to extend the protocol to require that conforming types are able to compare themselves against *any* Foo:

```
protocol Foo: Comparable { 
    // ... existing requirements

    func isEqual(to: Foo) -> Bool
    func isLessThan(_: Foo) -> Bool
}
```

Given those, you can construct whatever other algorithms you need. You can't use the default forms of `contains` or `sorted`, but you can use these functions in the `where` and `by` parameters.

You can also make this a little nicer by providing some default implementations:

```
extension Foo where Self: Equatable {
    func isEqual(to other: Foo) -> Bool {
        guard let other = other as? Self else {
            return false
        }
        return self == other
    }
}
```

And similarly for `isLessThan`.

And if you want things like `contains`, you can then also provide helpers if that's convenient:

```
extension Sequence where Element == Foo {
    func contains(_ element: Element) -> Bool {
        return contains(where: { $0.isEqual(to: element) })
    }
}
```

If you want a much longer version of this discussion, see [Generic Swift: It Isn't Supposed to Hurt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXwJg0QTlZE). This particular subject comes up at 37:40.